# Golang загрузка нескольких файлов из формы

Tags: golang

Имею простейшую форму для загрузки файлов:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <p><input type="file" name="f">
   <input type="submit" value="Отправить" multiple></p>
</form>
```

Код на Go, который загружает только **первый** файл:

```
r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20)
       file, handler, err := r.FormFile("f")
       if err != nil {
           fmt.Println(err)
           return
       }
       defer file.Close()
       fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v", handler.Header)
       f, err := os.OpenFile("./test/"+handler.Filename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
       if err != nil {
           fmt.Println(err)
           return
       }
       defer f.Close()
       io.Copy(f, file)
```

Как загрузить сразу все выбранные файлы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил следующим образом:

```
m, err := r.MultipartReader()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

for {
    part, err := m.NextPart()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }

    if part.FileName() == "" {
        continue
    }

    dst, err := os.Create("./test/" + part.FileName())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    io.Copy(dst, part)
}
```

[Оригинал](http://sanatgersappa.blogspot.ru/2013/03/handling-multiple-file-uploads-in-go.html)